# Trouble with a Sendkeys function

Tags: python, parameters, python-2.7, sendkeys

So I downloaded a version of Sendkeys for python 2.7. Its working great!...for letters and numbers that can be entered in a string.

The function is of the following form:

```
def SendKeys(keys, 
             pause=0.05, 
             with_spaces=False, 
             with_tabs=False, 
             with_newlines=False,
             turn_off_numlock=True):
    """
    Sends keys to the current window.

    `keys` : str
        A string of keys.
    `pause` : float
        The number of seconds to wait between sending each key
        or key combination.
    `with_spaces` : bool
        Whether to treat spaces as ``{SPACE}``. If `False`, spaces are ignored.
    `with_tabs` : bool
        Whether to treat tabs as ``{TAB}``. If `False`, tabs are ignored.
    `with_newlines` : bool
        Whether to treat newlines as ``{ENTER}``. If `False`, newlines are ignored.
    `turn_off_numlock` : bool
        Whether to turn off `NUMLOCK` before sending keys.

    example::

        SendKeys("+hello{SPACE}+world+1")

    would result in ``"Hello World!"``
    """
```

and these codes are given:

```
CODES = {
    'BACK':         8,
    'BACKSPACE':    8,
    'BS':           8,
    'BKSP':         8,
    'BREAK':        3,
    'CAP':          20,
    'CAPSLOCK':     20,
    'DEL':          46,
    'DELETE':       46,
    'DOWN':         40,
    'END':          35,
    'ENTER':        13,
    'ESC':          27,
    'HELP':         47,
    'HOME':         36,
    'INS':          45,
    'INSERT':       45,
    'LEFT':         37,
    'LWIN':         91,
    'NUMLOCK':      144,
    'PGDN':         34,
    'PGUP':         33,
    'PRTSC':        44,
    'RIGHT':        39,
    'RMENU':        165,
    'RWIN':         92,
    'SCROLLLOCK':   145,
    'SPACE':        32,
    'TAB':          9,
    'UP':           38,
    'DOWN':         40,
    'BACKSPACE':    8,
    'F1':           112,
    'F2':           113,
    'F3':           114,
    'F4':           115,
    'F5':           116,
    'F6':           117,
    'F7':           118,
    'F8':           119,
    'F9':           120,
    'F10':          121,
    'F11':          122,
    'F12':          123,
    'F13':          124,
    'F14':          125,
    'F15':          126,
    'F16':          127,
    'F17':          128,
    'F18':          129,
    'F19':          130,
    'F20':          131,
    'F21':          132,
    'F22':          133,
    'F23':          134,
    'F24':          135,
}
```

I just cannot figure out how to use them! Specifically I would like to be able to backspace.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Ignore all the values in the CODES dictionary. (That is, 8, 8, 8, 3, 20, 20, etc.) The only thing that matters are the keys ('BACK', 'BACKSPACE', 'BS', etc.), and you can use them by surrounding them with brackets and calling the function:

```
import SendKeys
send = "dirx{BACKSPACE}{ENTER}"
SendKeys.SendKeys(send)
```

That sends a "dir" command.

That's all there is to it!