# Use autoit to do an ENTER from within my python script

Tags: python-2.7, autoit

I need to execute an enter from my host machine once my command on the device connected to com port is done.
I tried the following but it doesn't seem to like it

```
import autoit
autoit.Send["{ENTER}"]
```

Comment: I think you're meant to use `Send("{Enter}")` and I'm not sure if that's your complete code block but use `Sleep` to wait for the connection to be established

Comment: Do I [miss something](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15804540/2152082)?